# Completely positive maps between matrix algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $n<m$ be natural numbers and consider the C*-algebras $M_n$ and $M_m$ of matrices. Suppose  that $f\colon M_n\to M_m$ is a a completely positive (linear) map. Is it true that

$$f(M_n)\subseteq \mbox{span}\{e_{i,j}\colon i\in I, j\in J\},$$

where $I$ and $J$ are some $n$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ consisting of **consecutive** integers, that is, are of the form $\{k+1\ldots, k+n\}$ for some $k<m$?

Comment: It might have nothing to do with it but this question makes me think of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209498/matrix-of-positive-definite

Comment: Not really, you are referring to Sylvester's criterion (which by the way is not valid for complex matrices).

Comment: That's not even true for *-homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said, that's not true even for *-monomorphisms. For example, consider $\pi:M_2(\mathbb C)\to M_4(\mathbb C)$, given by 
$$
\pi:\begin{bmatrix}a&b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}a&0&0&b\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\c&0&0&d\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is a $*$-monomorphism, so it is in particular completely positive.